# Callback or listener function for wordress elementor lightbox

Tags: wordpress, lightbox, elementor

I am trying to add a hover icon on all light box gallery elements so was looking out for any callback the elementor guys would provide ? Searched up github for elementor but couldnt find anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out elementor uses [DialogsManager](https://github.com/kobizz/dialogs-manager) having widget "lightbox" and here is how you can have the callback :

```
DialogsManager.getWidgetType("lightbox").prototype.onShow = function(){
   //perform your action here
}
```